# How can I fix "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request", when working with appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, cloud

I am doing a my school project and I keep on getting an error, when I am deploying my java (web application) on appengine:

```
       Error: Server Error

       The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
       If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

I have been working in parallel with a tutorial, following the same steps as in it: http://trumpy.cs.elon.edu/joel/sigcse2011/. I have been doing the same tutorial long long time ago, and it worked perfectly, but now I am redoing it with my very own data, I am just using it to have a structure that I am sure it works.

The problem is when I am trying to perform save in the datastore, I keep on getting this error. It might be because some eclipse updates I have been doing? Otherwise, I see no reason why this is not working (I've been rechecking my code over and over again, and I assume if it would've been a logical error or something I did wrong I should've receive another type of error).

I would like to add that the deployment is successful, and when I am accessing .appspot.com, I see the greeting message, but when I am clicking to lauch the servlet that performs the save operation, I get this error.

Thank you in advance and any help is appreciated.

LE: I have been trying to switch from app engine SDK 1.8.0 to 1.7.7, as I saw suggested in some websites, but with no successful result.

LE: This is how my log looks like and I am trying to figure out how to interpret it. Any help in this sense is appreciated and I am sorry for these questions but everything is new for me related to google app engine :):

```
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.classesDAO.projectServlet

javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: pack.classesDAO.projectServlet

Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@190d003{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~projectServlet/1.367688587833153738}
java.lang.NullPointerException

Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
```

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Some are quite intuitive so I'll look again, but some I have no idea what they mean.

Actually, this is the exception that I get now:

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
```

I have an idea from where it might be:

```
      double theHeadacke = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("headacke"));
```

But I am not sure what's wrong here.

Here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DiplomaThesisRoxana</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pack.servlets.DiplomaThesisRoxanaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiplomaThesisRoxana</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/diplomathesisroxana</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` means the specified class is not on the classpath. If `pack.classesDAO.projectServlet` is a class, then your app-engine can't find it. The rest of the exceptions are probably due to that one.

Comment: That's actually the package where I am having some of my classes (I tried to work a bit more organized and to arrange everything in 2-3 packages). I will try to fix it right now. Thank you for answering me :)

Comment: If `pack.classesDAO.projectServlet` is a package, then you have specified it at a place that expects a class name, so obviously it won't find a class. You can post your configuration if you want more details.

Comment: I have managed to succesfully eliminate the ClassNotFoundExceotion. Ot was rather silly, I have moved my servlet in another package and I thought eclipse will update all its referrences, but it didn't, so in web.xml is was the old class. After modifying it, I eliminated the first exception, but the other 3 are still there. Thank you :) I'll see what I can do further.

Comment: `req.getParameter()` returns `null` if there is no parameter in the request with the passed name. Check the client making the request is actually sending it (ex: that the html has a form input named `headacke`)

Comment: Hey! Thank you, I'd love to vote up your answers. indeed, the problem (after the one with the servlet), was generated because of the reqParameter(). Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad you found it, added an answer below for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs when the specified class is missing from your classpath. So `pack.classesDAO.projectServlet` is either not where you think it should be, is named differently, or just simply doesn't exist.

From your edit

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
I have an idea from where it might be:

      double theHeadacke = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("headacke"));
```

[`HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) returns `null` when there is no a parameter of that name in the HTTP request. Check that your client is sending it as part of the request. For example, you should have a form `<input>` element with the `name` attribute set to `headacke`.